# point cloud extraction

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm working with ROS on object identification.
but i don't know how your pointcloud node receives the sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 msg.
and also how to use pcl::fromROSMsg function to convert it to pcl::PointCloud

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11470/point-cloud-extraction/) by [youga](https://answers.ros.org/users/1191/youga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2011-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

look at the code towards the end of:

https://github.com/aa755/scene_labelling_rgbd/blob/release2/scene_processing/src/openni_listener.cpp

---

Originally posted by [aa755](https://answers.ros.org/users/303/aa755/) with karma: 61 on 2011-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1